# Build failed with error: Undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've created a new React Native project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`.

When I try to run ios app with `npx react-native run-ios`, build fails with the following error.

```
Undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow
```

I am using XCode 11.3.

After some research, I found that upgrading XCode version could solve the problem. But I cannot upgrade XCode version for some reason.

Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: What is the reason that prevents you from upgrading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try followings:

- comment all flipper function in podfile
- remove flipperInit in appDelegate
- remove openSSl in podfile.lock
- pod install,
- clean project
- run again

I could solve with this.

Comment: You can also just downgrade them instead of deleting them. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30231#issuecomment-738674682)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by downgrading React Native version to `0.61.5`.